# How can I draw a line of polygons in css?

Tags: css, drawing, polygon, draw, clip-path

I am required to draw the attached shape as a "section separator". The shape is polygons stacked next to one another with a bit of border-radius at the top.

Any help how to do it with CSS elegantly?

**The shape:**
[image]

Comment: I would use img.... or svg on repeat...

Comment: @EveryScreamer image is the easiest way but is it a div is more faster to load even on a very slow internet connection?

Comment: @ailia well if you use png or new formats and only part of that image and use repeat i think your image will be around 2-3kB and thats fine